# Ember JS property accessor

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I saw that given an Ember model `Book`:

```
export default Model.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
});
```

One can access the book's title property doing: `book.get('title');`.

This notation seems complicated and error-prone (no IDE support). Why do properties can't be accessed like:

- `book.title`
- or even `book.title()` ?

Is there a technical reason to do that, or it is just "the good way" to do it in JS ?

I hope the question is not stupid, I'm pretty new to those JS frameworks.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not specific to JS, the Get method is a simple method that takes a parameter and returns that value as opposed to creating multiple methods that just do one thing like book.title, book.preface, etc..

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but that forces the developer to handle things himself, right ? This seems convenient, but not very effective when writing things

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a little complicated. I'll try to explain it as concise as possible. properties in Ember can be computed and observed. for instance in your example if I did this:

```
export default Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.attr('string'),
  displayName: function(){
    return this.get('title') + " By: " + this.get('author');
  }.property('title','author')
});
```

So now I have a computed property that depends on two other properties.so when i call get('displayName'); I don't have to worry at all about if the property is observed, computed or if the prop is being used in a chain. this also insures that bindings and all of the built in ember stuff work correctly.

One of the principles of Ember is that the caller does not need to worry about how the ember-metal internals work or deal with the object.

Also using the .get() and .set() conventions adhere to the [Uniform access principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Assuming you could access properties like `book.title`, the `displayName` method's implementation could be written like this: `return this.title + " By: " + this.author`, and you could access it with `book.displayName` (this could work with parenthesis too). So I still don't see how this is a smart thing to do. Sorry, I may not getting your point :(